# SQLite ON CONFLICT fails to work for v3.8.11.1 (which comes with ubuntu by default)

Tags: sqlite

select sqlite_version(); 
INSERT INTO users (uuid, test_field) VALUES ('uuid1', '1.0);
INSERT INTO users (uuid) VALUES ('uuid1') ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE SET test_field = '1.1';

The above results in:
3.8.11.1
OK
ERROR: near "ON": syntax error

Why is it failing to recognize the ON word of ON CONFLICT

Comment: That upsert notation was added in 3.24.

Answer (score 0):

The us of `ON CONFLICT` is what is termed as an UPSERT and was only introduced in SQLite 3.24.0.

as per :-

> UPSERT is a special syntax addition to INSERT that causes the INSERT
>   to behave as an UPDATE or a no-op if the INSERT would violate a
>   uniqueness constraint. UPSERT is not standard SQL. UPSERT in SQLite
>   follows the syntax established by PostgreSQL. UPSERT syntax was added
>   to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)

As such it cannot be used in SQLite 3.8.11.1 and thus the SYNTAX error near **ON** as it's not a recognised keyword in that context.

Comment: That seems to be incorrect because I am not using the UPSERT word.  It is the ON CONFLICT phrase as described here: https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html   The ON CONFLICT clause described here has been a part of SQLite since before version 3.0.0 (2004-06-18). The phrase "ON CONFLICT" is also part of UPSERT, which is an extension to INSERT added in version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04). Do not confuse these two separate uses of the "ON CONFLICT" phrase.   This means the ON CONFLICT existed,  and is also utilized with UPSERT.  UPSERT was added in 3.24,  not ON CONFLICT. Im not using UPSERT.

Comment: Therefore since ON CONFLICT existed since 2004,  the above should work.  As far as I can tell, UPSERT is simply just an ALIAS of ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE,  which I dont agree should have been added as "UPSERT" is not an english word and makes no sense at all.

Comment: @totalnoob Using **DO ....** makes it an UPSERT.See as per *Do not confuse these two separate uses of the "ON CONFLICT" phrase.* [ON CONFLICT clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) You can use ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK/ABORT/FAIL/ IGNORE/REPLACE that is what has been available.

Comment: So lame,  so the REAL syntax error isnt the ON CONFLICT phase/word,  its the DO word :/  To confusing.

Comment: @totalnoob yes and no, it depends upon how you look at it. DO ... is what changes from old style to new but the entire statement cannot then be used in that form.